# Check if EditText Input is a String

Tags: android

I have an EditText Widget called input, which asks for the user's name and a Button, which displays it in a TextView called output when clicked. How can I test to make sure that the user is typing in a String value and not a bunch of integers? Is there any type of Exception that can be thrown here? Thank you.

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try{
                String name = input.getText().toString();
                //How can I find out if the user is typing in something 
                //other than a String here?
                output.setText(input.getText());

            }catch(NumberFormatException e){
                Log.v("Not a number", TAG);
                output.setError("Must Be A Number");
                output.setText("");
            }
```

Comment: Try regular expression...

Comment: a bunch of integers in a String too. You need to start by defining precisely what kind of input you want to allow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[^\\p{L}+]");
Matcher m = p.matcher(" input string ")
if(m.find())
    //do whatever you want when input has digits/ special characters/ white space
else 
    //valid string
```

Comment: Why not make the regex look for a string of all numbers, rather than just checking the English alphabet?

Comment: @LucasCrawford silly of me.. will update the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this one to check whether the edittext input is string or number

```
//it gives true if text is number else it return false
public static boolean isNumeric(String str)
{
    try
    {
        double d = Double.parseDouble(str);
    }
    catch(NumberFormatException nfe)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

or else you can try with this one:

```
String regexString = "^[0-9]*$";

if(editText.getText().toString().trim().matches(regexString))
 {
//it is digit
}
else{
//it is string
}
```